# NodeJS Redis client initialization best practices

Tags: node.js, redis

Hi I have a question related to using a redis client in NodeJS.

I am currently using `redis` package in my node backend and what I do is that at application startup I connect to my redis url and use the same for all my requests.

I'm having some issues when the client disconnects and server receives requests.
Those requests have to wait for redis to reconnect and sometimes take several seconds which results in a timeout.

A colleague of mine suggested to initialize a redis connection for each requests. What do you guys think about that ?

Comment: I think you should look at _why_ the client disconnects.

Comment: I think your colleague is really well informed. Please look at rule number 5 of redis' worst practices. https://redis.com/blog/7-redis-worst-practices/

Comment: @JeanJacquesGourdin i dont really understand if that's meant to be sarcastic or not ...? 
quote from your link : "However, well-meaning developers sometimes create a connection, run a command, and close the connection. **While opening and closing connections per command will technically work, it’s far from optimal** and needlessly cuts into the performance of Redis as a whole. [...] 
Best-practice alternative: **Keep your connections open over multiple commands**"

Comment: @robertklep we have a hint that it might be our firewall disconnecting it, but the redis reconnect takes forever at times which leads to pending/timeout requests

Comment: @SévrainCHEA running one query per connection is going to make _every_ request run slowly. At least check if it's possible to speed up the reconnect and/or use a connection pool (not sure if the Redis driver provides one itself or not), but in the end the main issue should be fixed.